# Is function formatted-datetime supported in Enterprise COBOL?

Tags: cobol, cobol-zos

I know that GNU COBOL supports the function `formatted-datetime`. Does IBM ENTERPRISE COBOL support this function?
I did an extensive search and found nothing in IBM documentation at hand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, but I believe it is only supported on Enterprise COBOL v6.3 with [PTF PH31047](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH31047).

You can check the [Language Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=functions-formatted-datetime) for details on the function.